# about SUBDOMAIN vs SUBFOLDER question again?

Tags: subdomain, subdirectory

I am planing to create a site,

where my root domain www.example.com has an index page where it will let the users CHOOSE 3 website

namely politics.example.com , games.example.com, news.com

or example.com/politics , example.com/games, example.com/news?

now, I dont know what to choose? a SUBFOLDER or SUBDOMAIN linking?

what i would like to happen is that whatever the click-rate from one of my link, it will be passed to my root domain which is example.com. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a subdomain, for example: `subdomain.example.com`, requests will be sent to `subdomain.example.com`, and not to `example.com` unless you program to do so explicitly. Clicking `example.com/subdomain` sends requests to `example.com`.

Comment: so it means, if my subdomain.example.com will have a page rank of 5 my example.com could have a page rank of 4 or less (different page rank?)

but when my example.com/subdomain . got a page rank of 5 , my example.com will got a pagerank of 5 too?

Comment: @pinoy: I am not sure about how page ranks are calculated. However, you can think of it like this: a subdomain and a domain can be totally different and can be on different servers.